# How to access Sim tool kit on modem

Tags: command-line, usb-modem, modem-manager

I have been trying to access the sim tool kit of my modem, but unfortunately not successful.

I saw a nice package called `modem manager gui`, which has a commandline tool `mmlci`.

Looking at it's manpage i've been trying various commands, in my case i wanted a way to access the sim tool kit that is on my simcard.

I tried using the AT commands but nothing seems to work, 
for example most of the commands i run give me this error

```
root@xxx:~# mmcli -m ${s_modem} --command=AT+ZSTM           
error: command failed: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.MobileEquipment.Unknown: Unknown error'
```

Can anyone give/show me a way to access sim tool kit using any ubuntu package

PS : am using a Huawei Modem

Comment: @user.dz can you help with this Sir?